# Import CSV with date column: Unable to encode value 'date' of feature null: invalid type Date

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm trying to import this csv file in GEE using the Google Earth Engine editor:

```
index,date,name,lat,lon
0,2021-01-01,Voronoi,0,0
1,2021-01-01,Thiessen,0,0
2,2021-01-01,Dirichlet,0,0
```

I want to import the `date` column in date format in Google Earth Engine. When I configure the date pattern as `yyyy-MM-dd` (see image), the process always fails with the error: `Error: Unable to encode value 'date' of feature null: invalid type Date. (Error code: 3)`

[image: GEE Configuration popup]

How can I import the CSV with the date column correctly?

Comment: I uploaded twice your CSV file without any problem (I used **copy/paste** from it in your question with two different names). It looks as an editor issue. By the way, what kind of text editor do you use? You must use only text plain editors (or a spreadsheets with option to save as CSV).

Comment: Thanks @xunilk. II've uploaded the file without date configured, and the file was imported correctly but I've tried again to upload the file and i've configured the date pattern (red rectangle of the screenshot)  to parse the date of the file and it's throwing the same error. I used a text plain editor to save the file. Did you test it setting the date pattern? (red rectangle of the screenshot). Thanks.

Comment: Try **yyyy-mm-dd**.

Comment: @xunilk `yyyy-mm-dd` doesn't work because `mm` representes minutes instead of months. Thanks